# PHP how to use preg_replace to replace (90) in a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a big problem understanding how to use preg_replace.
I need to replace the string FROM:

```
GPCNT2(90)>GPBRL2(90)>GPDUT1(180)>GPJDPR TO: GPCNT2>GPBRL2>GPDUT1>GPJDPR
```

What regular expression should I use to accomplish this?

Current code:

```
if(strpos($route_path, '/(\d+)/') !== false) { 
  $route_path = preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '', $route_path); 
  echo "<br>" .$route_path."</br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Here is my code...

if(strpos($route_path, '/\(\d+\)/') !== false)
{
$route_path = preg_replace('/\(\d+\)/', '', $route_path);
echo "<br>" .$route_path."</br>";
}

Comment: But I could not convert it FROM GPCNT2(90)>GPBRL2(90)>GPDUT1  TO GPCNT2>GPBRL2>GPDUT1.
Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strpos`, use `preg_match`. You also need to **escape** the parenthesis `\(`

here you go:

```
<?php
$route_path = "GPCNT2(90)>GPBRL2(90)>GPDUT1(180)>GPJDPR";
if(preg_match('/\(\d+\)/', $route_path)) { 
  $route_path = preg_replace('/\(\d+\)/', '', $route_path); 
  echo "<br>" .$route_path."</br>"; 
}
//</br>GPCNT2>GPBRL2>GPDUT1>GPJDPR</br>
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/0DOiXr)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I solve it like this & it works...

if ((strpos($route_path, '-') !== false) || (strpos($route_path, '>>') !== false) || (strpos($route_path, '(') !== false)) 
{
$route_path = preg_replace('/\(\d+\)/', '', $route_path);
 $route_path= str_replace(array('-', '>>'), '>', $route_path);
echo "<br>" .$route_path."</br>";
}

Comment: You're very welcome @sharvanaz but your solution isn't related in any way with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is **GPCNT2(90)>GPBRL2(90)>GPDUT1(180)>GPJDPR** a String? 
If it is; then you may want to try something like this:

```
<?php 
    $str           = "GPCNT2(90)>GPBRL2(90)>GPDUT1(180)>GPJDPR";
    $strFiltered   = preg_replace("#(\(\d*\))(>)#i", "$2", $str);

    //COMPARE THE RESULTS TO SEE IF ALL IS OK AS YOU DESIRED IT...
    var_dump($str);
    var_dump($strFiltered);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I solve it like this & it works...
 if ((strpos($route_path, '-') !== false) || (strpos($route_path, '>>') !== false) || (strpos($route_path, '(') !== false)) 
{
 $route_path = preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '', $route_path); 
$route_path= str_replace(array('-', '>>'), '>', $route_path); 
echo "<br>" .$route_path."</br>"; 
}